# Dalvik VM vs Sun JVM

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can you not do on the Dalvik VM (Android’s VM) that you can in Sun VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230193/what-can-you-not-do-on-the-dalvik-vm-androids-vm-that-you-can-in-sun-vm)

What ever interviews i have faced.In every interview when interviewers come on android topic they ask this question.
"what is the difference between Dalvik VM vs Sun JVM?".
i have given some answers like.
[What can you not do on the Dalvik VM (Android's VM) that you can in Sun VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230193/what-can-you-not-do-on-the-dalvik-vm-androids-vm-that-you-can-in-sun-vm)

but i think they wanted more.

Comment: If you want more, start a bounty on that question then. Don't ask a dupe. See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: i think this question is a different question.difference between A and B is not only what you can't do with A.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they're not referring to the differences in the APIs? I mean both JVMs are turing complete, so basically they can do the same things.

One internal difference is that the sun JVM is stack-based, while Dalvik is register based. (It has an infinite number of registers though.) But that doesn't really explain what you can/can't do on it.

Comment: you are right with "sun JVM is stack-based, while Dalvik is register based" i don't want can/can't. in that post also some differences are given so i have given the example of that post.