# JAR interdependencies in Android

Tags: android, jar, dependencies, runtime, classloader

I have an android app that reads some classes from external JARs at runtime. I am using the PathClassLoader.

I'm getting an instantiation exception with classes in JARs that depend on things in other JARs. In Android I can't find any way to add multiple sources for a classloader that works, nor does chaining the classloaders together as child and parent seem to work.

I could move all the classes into one JAR for my deployment, or maybe unpack all the classes at runtime, however it would be far better if I could find some more convenient and less 'brute force' way to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that android's dalvik VM is not the same as the java one.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230193/what-can-you-not-do-on-the-dalvik-vm-androids-vm-that-you-can-in-sun-vm).

In an Android application you place all your jars in `/lib/` and the compiler will take care of placing them correctly in the `dex` file.

Comment: This is about loading from JARs at rintime.