# Using Dalvik VM On Server for Web Development?

Tags: java, jvm, web

I am wondering if there are limitation stopping Dalvik VM work as a Server VM? A Previous discussion already stats that most of java code should work. Since Dalvik VM uses less memory, which would be very useful for VPS users.

Are there anything similar being done? I Did a google search and found Zero things. Am i missing something? That is can not be used this way?

Answer (score 1):

DalvikVM is not a ["standard"(pdf)](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aOySlqRyj_L0J%3adavidehringer.com/software/android/The_Dalvik_Virtual_Machine.pdf%20davlik%20vm%20web%20server&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgc_6uZcK1MFUszRotYeWWTf2-s8sF4sUKEoPbF8Op6CVpH9dnwNFU7fjB2_fE7ThyZHNMSkc4kkLk4FkZETvdqyKqwtje8rRRJRiLTLRD0xOj6Uh9LQKPCf4vSoQMpcGNG71Rm&sig=AHIEtbTwEbiDiLE636bOcaMlrerU0a2DWg) JVM. It's a JVM explicitly geared towards operating on a mobile device and it runs a modified version of Java. Using this as a webserver would be a bad idea, particularly on the grounds that it doesn't [fully support JavaSE (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) and it doesn't even mention having support for J2EE.

Comment: Well according to another question on StackExchange, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230193/what-can-you-not-do-on-the-dalvik-vm-androids-vm-that-you-can-in-sun-vm

Comment: Yes, however, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230193/what-can-you-not-do-on-the-dalvik-vm-androids-vm-that-you-can-in-sun-vm/2389218#2389218 answer in the question. Dalvik was designed with mobile as its primary market, not being a general JVM.

Comment: Of course it would not be a drop in replacement for JavaSE, but I would like to see a Dalvik server.